# Android live streaming using wowza + libstreaming

Tags: java, android, wowza, libstreaming

I wanted to stream live video with the help of the wowza server. Currently am using `libstreaming` along with wowza and it works fine.

It works fine with WiFi. 4mbps speed.

But Problem comes when it is connected to 3G, even when it is at least resolution -> `320x240`. It gets pixelated, faded, and sometimes stops.

Is there anything i can do stuff like buffering the video rather getting pixelated/faded/poor quality video ?

Is there any API other than `libstreaming` ?

Thanks

Comment: I am also working with libstreaming examples its working fine in 3g, it may be a issue with your network

Comment: are you using wowza?

Comment: ya its working with both wowza and nginx

Comment: 3g Network provider is Airtel India

Comment: you have created your own real time streaming server?

Comment: ya i am having my own server

Comment: hey ! I created a server of my own as well. There is a lag using Wifi, can you please share the configuration for the nginx server. would be really helpful..

Comment: what kind of lag your facing frame drop?

Comment: its about 2 to 3 sec which is at a very high speed. 

am worried about 3G.. if its there is a 2 3 sec lag on high speed internet then there will be a great amount of lag in 3g..

Comment: I am also having 5 sec of delay while watching the stream in WiFi connection with a speed of 20 mbps,i think 2 to 3 sec is alright

Comment: which android api are you using to send rtmp data to the server ?

Comment: I used lib stream example 3

Comment: Can you share the link please

Comment: I suppose lib stream doesn't support rtmp

Comment: https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming-examples/tree/master/example3/app

Comment: I think it works with rtsp in wowza

Comment: Yea it does Anyway thanks..!

Comment: Actually I have installed nginx and it supports just rtmp, so right now am in a fix which library to use

Comment: if you want to use rtmp video streaming check for java cv libs

Comment: I have implemented that but its crashing after sometime

Comment: @Giridharan..is libstreaming supports RTMP

Sahni sahab which technology stacks you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Can you measure the actual bandwidth your service provider gives to you for streaming protocol over 3G? Some SPs deliberately give less priority to streaming (or torrent).

My idea is that this might be the root cause..